# rrdtool fetch returns all -nan

Tags: ubuntu, cron, rrdtool

### Create db:

```
rrdtool create test.rrd --step 60 --start N DS:mem:GAUGE:60:U:U RRA:LAST:0.5:12:24 RRA:MAX:0.5:12:24 RRA:MIN:0.5:12:24 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:24
```

### Then I create get_mem.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/local/rrdtool/bin/rrdtool:/usr/local/rrdtool/bin/rrdtool:/home/parallels/bin:/home/parallels/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:$PATH


RRDTOOL='/usr/local/rrdtool/bin/rrdtool'
FILE='test.rrd'
COMMAND=`cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | awk '{print $1}'`
$RRDTOOL updatev $FILE N:$COMMAND
echo $COMMAND >> log.txt
```

## and cron task:

```
0-55/1 * * * * ./get_mem.sh
```

I tried to run from myself and from root (result is similar)

So, I try to fetch my values:

```
rrdtool fetch test.rrd AVERAGE -s 1509908400
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wItd0.png)

(all fetch types show -nans)

dump is similar: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA15c.png)

log.txt (just make sure): [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAurW.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say how many data samples you have added; you'll need at least 13 to have any chance of anything other then NaN in your output.

You definitely have these problems --

- Your Step size is 60s, but your DS Heartbeat is also 60s.  This means you need to have samples *more often* than 59s for them to be valid.  Generally, your heartbeat should be twice the step size.
- Your cronjob is collecting data every minute from 0 to 55.  What about minutes 56-59?  Also, if this is collecting every minute, then this is right on your heartbeat boundary, so it will likely store NaN.
- Your smallest RRA has 1cdp=12pdp.  This might be what you want; but bear in mind that you'll need 12 sequential valid data points in order to get one entry in your RRA.  Maybe add an RRA with 1cdp=1pdp?

I would suggest you create the RRD like this:

```
rrdtool create test.rrd --step 60 --start N \
    DS:mem:GAUGE:120:0:U \
    RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:24 \
    RRA:LAST:0.5:12:24 RRA:MAX:0.5:12:24 \
    RRA:MIN:0.5:12:24 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:24
```

Comment: @DanielMur - if all is OK, please click to accept the answer and mark it up (that way I get more points and feel warmer fuzzies inside)